# In Backbone.js, how can I fetch data from a URL?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to get tweets to pull from a URL, which returns data in the form of:

```
[
  {"user":"someuser1","tweet":"this is a #tweet","date":"2011-09 02"},
  {"user":"someuser2","tweet":"and this is a #tweet","date":"2011-09 02"},
  {"user":"someuser3","tweet":"and this is another #tweet","date":"2011-09"}
]
```

I have a model,

```
window.Tweet = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    this.bind('change',function(){
    })
  },
  defaults: {
    "user": "some-other-user",
    "tweet": "this is some tweet",
    "date" : "2012-01-06"
  }
});
```

I have a collection,

```
window.Tweets = Backbone.Collection.extend(null,{
    url: '/tweets/',
    model: Tweet,
    parse: function(response) {
      return response.results;
    }
});
```

and I have a view

```
window.TweetsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#content-top'),
    initialize: function(){
        this.model.bind('change',this.render,this);
    },
    render: function() {

      var TweetsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model : Tweet,
        url: '/tweets/',
        parse: function(response) {
          return response.results;
        }
      });

    var tweets = new TweetsCollection;
    tweets.fetch();

    console.log(tweets.toJSON());

   } ...
```

Both

```
alert(tweets.at(0));
```

and

```
alert(tweets.length)
```

give me "Undefined." What am I missing?

EDIT

If I log the response (in the view), I do get something back:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

so, I'm close, but still missing something.

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but did you do `(new TweetsView()).render()`?

Comment: Yes (not a dumb question :). I realize now I left off the parse function, I added it (updated the code above), but still getting an empty array [] when I log to the console.

Comment: when you call render(), you should see a GET request in firebug.  What is the response there?

Comment: I'm getting [{"user":"someuser1","tweet":"this is a #tweet","date":"2011-09 02"}, {"user":"someuser2","tweet":"and this is a #tweet","date":"2011-09 02"}, {"user":"someuser3","tweet":"and this is another #tweet","date":"2011-09"}]

Comment: The above response comes from http://localhost:3000/tweets//

Comment: what does it look like if you log `response[0]`?  That's odd that you're seeing objects instead of the data you're receiving.  Assuming the server is sending the data down as json, Firebug should be displaying them with their info (unless you're using Safari/Chrome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, I would say the data is coming in right.

Try adding `console.log(response);` in your parse function.

In my backbone models, the parse() method just returns the first argument, which would be response in your case.  I think you need to just change

```
return response.results;
```

to

```
return response;
```

Comment: That's definitely getting me somewhere Eric, it logs 3 objects. Immediately after that Backbone.js (0.5.3) is throwing the error:

Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function

Comment: Found the problem, Eric--thank you for your help. I had a namespaced model in the Collection constructor, model: App.Tweet, and that was throwing things off. After I removed that it was good and I'm now getting the response I was after.